# On click get value of element several parents up using jquery

Tags: jquery

Here is html i'm working with:

```
<ul id="sortable-row" class="ui-sortable">
        <li id="1" class="ui-sortable-handle">
            Dropdown Question:
            <input class="fieldtype" type="hidden" value="dropdown" name="fieldtype[]">
            <input class="amountofoptions" type="hidden" name="amountofoptions[]" value="2">
            <input class="questionname" type="text" name="questionname[]">
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-primary adddropdownoptionbutton" type="button">add option</button>
            <ul class="dropdown-options-row">
                <li class="anoption">
                    Option:
                    <input class="dropdownoptionname" type="text" name="dropdownoptionname[]" value="">
                    <span class="ex">x</span>
                </li>
                <li class="anoption">
                    Option:
                    <input class="dropdownoptionname" type="text" value="" name="dropdownoptionname[]">
                    <span class="ex">x</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

When clicking the "x", i want to grab the value of "amountofoptions". I tried many different variations of parent(), closest(), and sibling(), but couldn't get anything to work. I can't paste all the different things I tried because I was somewhere else. I am at home now with no access to that other computer, but any suggestions I get now I can test on my home wamp server (or when I get back to other computer tomorrow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`amountofoptions` not a siblings nor parent of `ex`, then you need to get the closest parent which is a sibling of `amountofoptions` that is `ul` element. Then you can select `amountofoptions` by using [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) or [`prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/) like so:

```
$('.ex').click(function(){
  // for the best case, we use prevAll as we want
  // to select `amountofoptions` element that is located
  // before the UL element
  var a = $(this).closest('ul').prevAll('.amountofoptions').val();
  // or you can use below line of code using .find()
  var a = $(this).closest('.ui-sortable').find('.amountofoptions').val();
  // or this, this is worst but work, not recommended this
  var a = $(this).closest('ul').prev().prev().prev().val();
  // or by .siblings() like so :
  var a = $(this).closest( "ul" ).siblings(".amountofoptions").val()
  alert(a);
});
```

Well you can choose 1 of 4 methods above and here is 
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/y4q22yz6/).

Comment: thanks for choices. seems to work on a simple page with nothing but this code. not sure if the app i'm working with somewhere else has jquery conflicts or something, but will let you know how it goes tomorrow and mark as correct answer if it works.

Comment: Yes, be sure the HTML structure well structured as jQuery selector depend on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Like this

```
$(".ex").on("click",function(){
  console.log($(this).closest( "ul" ).siblings(".amountofoptions").val());
})
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/56h0rdj0/)

Comment: use .ex ...instead of ex

Comment: this one seems to work too. will let you know tomorrow when i can apply it on the app i'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `parents()` or any other traversal methods. I would first advise changing each of your `<span>` to `<button>` for semantics, and then apply an `id` to create a distinction between your two buttons. Code withstanding, the JS would be:

```
var displayValue = function(el){
    return el.val();
}

var $x_button = $('.ex');
var $amt = $('.amountofoptions');

$x_button.click(function(){
    displayValue($amt);
});
```